# What is the Milne-Eddington Approximation?

Tags: planet, solar-system, planetary-atmosphere, temperature, radiation

In this paper: [Planet temperatures with surface cooling parameterized](http://saspcsus.pbworks.com/w/file/fetch/64696386/planet%20temperatures%20with%20surface%20cooling%20parameterized.pdf) it states in the "radiation model" the following:

> The Eddington–Milne approximation relates $T_0$ and $T_e$ through the
> gray IR optical depth $\tau$:
>
> $T_0=T_e(1+\frac{3}{4}\tau)^{0.25}$

I looked this approximation up on google, and found it was more commonly known as the Milne-Eddington Approximation. However, this approximation seems to (mainly) be applied to stars, and I can't exactly see the connection between it and the temperature of a planet. (I also don't completely understand what an "optical depth" is.)

What is this approximation and why can it be applied to approximate the temperature of a planet with an atmosphere?

Comment: The [optical depth](https://scienceworld.wolfram.com/physics/OpticalDepth.html) is "a measure of how opaque a medium is to radiation passing through it" which intuitively means relates to how far you can see into the atmosphere from outside for a given wavelength. I am stumbling upon the "gray" in your quote though - is "gray IR" a commonly accepted term?

Comment: "Gray" opacity or optical depth generally means "wavelength-independent", i.e. it is assumed to be the same at all wavelengths.  I haven't seen it used to modify IR before, but from context I take it to mean the assumption of a constant optical depth across some limited range of wavelengths, here the infrared (or part of it - the IR is huge as a part of the EM spectrum!)

Comment: @eshaya I did find another source that indeed had 1/2 instead of 1. Do you have a source that derives the equation?

Answer (score 2):

I don't have time to write up a full answer with derivation, but you might want to have a look into the standard radiation transport literature (e.g. the book by Mihalas & Mihalas) or the radiation transport in stellar interiors (e.g. Kippenhahn) or literature for irradiated exoplanets, see e.g. [Guillot (2010)](https://ui.adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2010A%26A...520A..27G/abstract).

**The Milne-Eddingtion-approximation (short: ME-approximation) is a standard *result* for grey radiation transport in another approximation**, i.e. at optical depths >1, when the radiation flux is diffusive:

$$F_{\rm rad} = \frac{c}{3\rho \kappa_R} \nabla E_{\rm rad}$$

Then you can couple the equations for $\rm E_{rad}$ and $\rm E_{gas}$, integrate and solve for $\rm E_{gas}$, which is $\rm \rho c_vT$. This gives you the ME relation, which is valid for the diffusive radiative transport in gases, and precludes interesting things like the greenhouse-effect, temperature inversions, etc.